# Please suggest hardware configuration for network-intensive Flink job (Async I/O)

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-flink, amazon-emr, flink-batch

TLDR; I am running Flink Streaming job in mode=Batch on EMR. I have tried several EMR cluster configurations but neither of them works as required. Some do not work at all. Workflow is very network-intensive that cases main problems.

**Question: What EMR cluster configuration (ec2 instance types) would you recommend for this use-case?**

--

The job has following stages:

1. Read from MySQL
2. KeyBy user_id
3. Reduce by user_id
4. Async I/O enriching from Redis
5. Async I/O enriching from other Redis
6. Async I/O enriching from REST #1
7. Async I/O enriching from REST #2
8. Async I/O enriching from REST #2
9. Write to Elasticsearch

Other info:

Flink version: 1.13.1
EMR version: 6.4.0
Java version: JDK version Corretto-8.302.08.1 (provided by EMR)
Input data size: ~800 GB
Output data size: ~300 GB

- "taskmanager.network.sort-shuffle.min-parallelism": 1
- "taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.batch-shuffle.size": 256m
- "taskmanager.network.sort-shuffle.min-buffers": 2048
- "taskmanager.network.blocking-shuffle.compression.enabled": true
- "taskmanager.memory.framework.off-heap.size": 512m
- "taskmanager.memory.network.max": 2g

Configurations we tried:

**#1**

master: r6g.xlarge

core: r6g.xlarge (per/hour: $0.2; CPU: 4; RAM: 32 GiB; Disk: EBS 128 GB, network: 1.25 Gigabit baseline with burst up to 10 Gigabit)

min_scale: 2

max_scale: 25

- expected: finishes within 24 hours
- actual: works with [sort-based shuffling](https://flink.apache.org/2021/10/26/sort-shuffle-part1.html) enabled but very slowly (~36h), as this type of instance has a baseline & burst performance, when burst credits are exhausted degrades to the baseline of 1GBps, that slows down I/O. With hash-based shuffling fails on KeyBy -> Reduce with "Connection reset by peer", Task Manager fails -> Job fails -> Job manager is not able to restart.

**#2**

master: m5.xlarge

core: r6g.12xlarge (per/hour: $2.4; CPU: 48; RAM: 384 GiB; Disk: EBS 1.5 TB, network: 20 Gigabit)

min_scale: 1

max_scale: 4

- expected: finishes within 24 hours, as there is much higher network badwith
- actual: does not work. With sort-based shuffling fails on the writing phase with exception "Failed to transfer file from TaskExecutor". With hash-based shuffling fails on the same stage with "Connection reset by peer".